# Next.js app crashes when attempting to implement google firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am running into an issue while trying to implement authentication with firebase (via google) within my next.js app, and am consistently seeing the app crash. I will show the code for the auth.js page component, as well as where I configure firebase and define the login and logout functions.

Here is the firebase-config.js file which is stored in the root of the project:

```
import { initializeApp,  } from 'firebase/app';
import { initializeAuth, browserLocalPersistence, browserPopupRedirectResolver, indexedDBLocalPersistence, signInWithRedirect, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseCredentials = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseCredentials);

export const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: [indexedDBLocalPersistence, browserLocalPersistence],
});

export const getUserFirebase = () => {
  return auth.currentUser;
};

export const loginFirebase = () => {
  signInWithRedirect(auth, new GoogleAuthProvider(), browserPopupRedirectResolver);
};

export const logoutFirebase = () => {
  signOut(auth);
};
```

Here is the auth.js component:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { IconButton, Menu, MenuItem, Button, Box } from '@mui/material';
import { AccountCircle, Logout, ManageAccounts, RateReview, Google } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { getUserFirebase, loginFirebase, logoutFirebase } from '../firebase-config';


export const Auth = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const handleMenu = (event) => setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  const handleClose = () => setAnchorEl(null);
  const redirectFromMenu = (url) => {
    handleClose();
    router.push(url);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
      {getUserFirebase() ? (
        <>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            aria-label="account of current user"
            aria-controls="menu-appbar"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={handleMenu}
            color="inherit"
            >
            <AccountCircle />
          </IconButton>
          <Menu
            id="menu-appbar"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: 'top',
              horizontal: 'right',
            }}
            keepMounted
            transformOrigin={{
              vertical: 'top',
              horizontal: 'right',
            }}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}
          >
            <MenuItem onClick={() => redirectFromMenu('/account')}><ManageAccounts />&nbsp;My Account</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => redirectFromMenu('/reviews/write')}><RateReview />&nbsp;Write Review</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={logoutFirebase}><Logout />&nbsp;Logout</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </>
      ) : (
        <Button size='small' onClick={loginFirebase} startIcon={<Google />} variant='contained' color='secondary'>
          Login with Google
        </Button>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

When attempting to log the `auth` object, it contains an error that states:

> 'dependent-sdk-initialized-before-auth': 'Another Firebase SDK was
> initialized and is trying to use Auth before Auth is initialized.
> Please be sure to call `initializeAuth` or `getAuth` before starting
> any other Firebase SDK.'

The app either gets `killed` on startup, or this occurs when trying to authenticate. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Does this error persist if you leave out the auth persistence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are not using Server-Side rendering.
If so, you need to expose those environment variables to the browser.

In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

In your *env* file,

```env
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY=******************
...
...
```

and you can access in your app like below,

```js
apiKey:  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY
```

Comment: After adding this to all the environment variables, it is just getting "killed" on start up

Comment: I realised that I was running out of memory haha. This worked.